# How many users will I lose with iOS permission prompts?

Tags: ios, user-research, mobile-application

Let's say I have an app, and I need to request a permission from the user to use the main use case of the app. This permission request happens the first time that the user opens the app.

- **Scenario A**: I display a prompt "in-app", saying "We'll need this permission to do this and that", giving context and when the user clicks "OK", I show them the iOS prompt for the device permission.
- **Scenario B**: I display the iOS prompt directly on start-up.

I know that each mandatory prompt you display on first start will cause you to lose some users. My question is: are there scientific studies, or trustworthy results, who indicate how many are lost by each of the two options? Does scenario A lose more users because there are two prompts? If so, how many?

Note that I'm only interested in the user loss rate. This question is specifically *not* about good practices or user happiness.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of any study regarding how many users are lost permanently, but I've seen statistics for the number of users who declined the permissions.

The most detailed example is [this article from the designer at Cluster](https://techcrunch.com/2014/04/04/the-right-way-to-ask-users-for-ios-permissions/).

**Results:**

- The headline figures are that **30-40%** of users accepted permissions
  **when asked the first time** they load up the app.
- By **educating the user before** asking for the permission, this
  increased acceptance to **66%**.
- By only asking for the permission **when the user triggers the

  functionality** which requires it, their acceptance rates were nearly
  at **100%**. This was attributed to the user better understanding what
  the permission was for.

Comment: The last point is exactly how Android reworked the persmission system lately (since v. 6 I believe). Only asking for permission when the user expects it makes them think "well yeah, this is reasanoble" instead of "why do you need this?"

Comment: The question I'm more interested in is: assuming the user is educated (for scenario A, in the in-app prompt, for scenario B, in the iOS prompt), would solution A (which allows for better "education", since you can add graphic elements, display account name, etc.) lose more users than solution B. But nonetheless, thanks! This is useful info.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but your Scenario A is the same as the "Benefit Explanation" method in the Cluster article (66%), and your Scenario B is the same as the "Initial Blitzkrieg" method (30-40%).